# Maven plugin development - how to ensure building for Maven 3.0.x instead of 3.1.x?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-mojo

I'm trying to develop a custom Maven plugin. I'm currently running into this problem when I execute my unit tests: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession` Stack trace is below:

```
initializationError(com.mycompany.MyPluginTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  (TestSuite.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:516)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:63)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:310)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:153)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.(TestSuite.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

From my research, this can happen when building for Maven 3.1.x because Maven switched from the sonatype aether implementation to the eclipse implementation.

I am trying to build my plugin for Eclipse **3.0.4**, since that's what's installed on all our workstations. I'm assuming that I'm seeing this error because one of my dependencies is a Maven 3.1.x dependency, although I'm not sure which one. Does anyone know which dependency I should correct?

Also, does anyone know if it's possible to build a plugin that will work for Maven 3.0.x and 3.1.x? I'd rather not have to go through all this again some day in the future when we move to a newer version of Maven.

The dependencies in my POM look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you show your plugin code? May be github project?

Comment: Anyone else find it ironic that the people maintaining the test fixtures for the dependency management build tool did dependency management wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so I think I figured out the issue with aether: it appears to depend on which version of `maven-plugin-testing-harness` is being used. Version <= 2.1 seems to use sonatype aether. Using this set of dependencies resolves the aether problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- version 2.1 uses sonatype aether. anything after 2.1 uses eclipse aether. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Basically if you consider the provided dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/3.3.0 you have the list of the dependency you have to include. I have spot this reading your answer and having a look at the mvncentral. IMHO should be just a dependency to add, clear and simple to make the test easier.

Answer (score 10):

Slightly more confusingly than moving to the eclipse aether dependency, a lot of the dependencies of the `maven-plugin-testing-harness` had the scope changed from `compile` to `provided` which means they're not resolved by your downstream dependency.

It seems like this was actually experienced in [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=988977) as well, and they raised [this issue with apache](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPLUGINTESTING-35) which hasn't had an attention in over a year...

On they apache bug, they state that you'll have to add dependencies on `maven-core, maven-model, maven-aether-provider` but on having a look at the dependencies of `maven-plugin-testing-harness` there are other `provided` scope dependencies.

The dependencies I had to add to persuade everything to work with plugin testing harness 3.3 were:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.javadoc</version>
    <type>javadoc.jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Glad you linked the associated bug.  I wish all 2500+ viewers of this question would just go vote on it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, interesting and weird enough, answers provided above didn't work for me. Did some digging around and found nothing. Finally came full circle when visited the plugin URL: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/dependency-convergence.html

The "Dependency Convergence" section provides all dependencies versions required to ensure the plugin 'lights up'. In a matter of seconds all was working. Here's a snippet of what I eventually had in my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps someone out there :)