# Maven build fails with error message Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test)

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm getting this error while trying to "clean install" a Spring project with Maven.

Below is the section of "maven-surefire-plugin"

```
<!-- BEGIN: Specific to mapping unit tests and covered code -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>coverage-per-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>600</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
                        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                        <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
                        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<!-- END: Specific to mapping unit tests and covered code -->
```

and here's the error :

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project common-jpa2ddl: There are test failures.
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project common-jpa2ddl: There are test failures.
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.697 sec
Running com.teamwill.common.jpa2ddl.Jpa2DDLTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(com.teamwill.common.jpa2ddl.Jpa2DDLTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystemSession
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.hasSuiteMethod(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:18)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.teamwill.common.jpa2ddl.Jpa2DDLTest): org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystemSession
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide the dependencies declared in your pom.xml ?
Also, you could take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310083/maven-plugin-development-how-to-ensure-building-for-maven-3-0-x-instead-of-3-1

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Running from command line?

Comment: here is my [pom.xml](https://github.com/ghassen1khalil/common-jpa2ddl/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using Maven 3.2.5, both from Eclipse and command line generate the same error !

Answer (score 0):

try to execute below command so that Maven will correct all the dependencies and its verisons
mvn dependency:tree
This has resolved in a similar issue.